# I have a little problem trying to understand differentials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, chain-rule

I have just learned differentials and I have a few things unclear. For example I found a contradiction trying to differentiate the function $f(f(x))$, where $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.
Using the chain rule we get $$(f(f(x)))'=f'(f(x))f'(x)$$
However, if we use the differentials we get that $$\frac{d(f(f(x)))}{dx}=\frac{df}{df}\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx}$$
This is true if $f(x)$ is a constant or $f(f(x))=f(x)$. Why doesn't this work for the general case?

Comment: Consider a substitution of $y=f(x)$. By the chain rule,$$\frac{df(f(x))}{dx} = \frac{df(y)}{dx} = \frac{df(y)}{dy}\times\frac{dy}{dx}$$That is,$$\frac{df(f(x))}{dx} = \frac{df(f(x))}{df(x)} \times \frac{df(x)}{dx}$$